# Prove that the complex roots of $\tan(x)-k$ cancel out

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I used a flismy "proof":

Consider the equation $\tan(x)=1$

The real roots of the equation are: $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$

Resulting in the values:$\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{-3\pi}{4},\dfrac{5\pi}{4},\dfrac{-7\pi}{4},\dfrac{9\pi}{4},\dfrac{-11\pi}{4}.\cdots$

Now we know that the sum of the reciprocals of the roots of a polynomial:

$\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i}}=-\dfrac{F'(0)}{F(0)}$

Here; $\dfrac{4}{\pi}-\dfrac{4}{3\pi}+\dfrac{4}{5\pi}-\dfrac{4}{7\pi}+\dfrac{4}{9\pi}-\dfrac{4}{11\pi}+\cdots+\sum\dfrac{1}{Imaginary Roots}=\dfrac{-\sec^2(0)}{\tan(0)-1}=1$

Therefore $\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sum\dfrac{1}{Imaginary Roots}+(\dfrac{1}{1}-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}-\dfrac{1}{11}+\cdots)$

Now, $\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sum{\dfrac{1}{Real_i}}=$$(\dfrac{1}{1}-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}-\dfrac{1}{11}+\cdots)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$(Leibniz's $\pi$ formula)

Therefore $\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sum{\dfrac{1}{ImgRoots_i}}=0=>\sum{{ImgRoots_i}}=0$

The problem with my method of "proving" is that I am using a known summation at a certain value of k,(k=1).

The result is true for any value of k(Eg, $k=\sqrt{3}$ results in a Dirichlet-L function summation  which is also entirely the Real value).

However I feel like I'm missing the real way to prove the result. How do I prove that the summation of the complex roots of $\tan(x)-k$ is $0$?

Comment: There are none when $k$ is real.

Comment: Ohhh thank you but how do I prove this though?

Comment: And the known summation you are using is actually not absolutely convergent, which means the sum is, as you've calculated it, slightly arbitrarily defined. One way around this is to consider $$\int_{\gamma_m}\frac{F'(z)}{F(z)}\,dz$$ where $\gamma_m$ is a circle of radius $m\pi$ and take the limit $m\to\infty$ But as Trebor notes, when $k$ is real, there are no non-real roots.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. However I don't understand the notation you used :) Is it meant to denote a contour integration or something?

Also how do I prove that there are no non real roots of $\tan(x)-k$?

Comment: Yeah, you won't have an easy way to see that integral if you don't know Cauchy's integral formula, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There are no non-real roots when $k$ is real.

We have:
$$\tan(z)=\frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}.$$ So for $\tan z$ to be real, $\phi(w)=\frac{w-1}{w+1}$ must be imaginary when $w=e^{2iz}.$

But $\phi^{-1}(y)=\frac{1+y}{1-y}.$

And if $y=ik$ is imaginary, then $|1+y|=|1-y|=\sqrt{1+k^2}$ and $|w|=\left|\phi^{-1}(y)\right|=1.$

So the only way for $\tan z$ to be real is for $\left|e^{2iz}\right|=1.$ If $z=a+bi,$ with $a,b$ real, then $\left|e^{2iz}\right|=e^{-2b},$ so $b=0$ is the only possibility, and $z$ must be real.